# Why is this query resolving to a DataQuery

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq to sql query that gets all my logs for the current hour(Stored as an Iqueryable):

```
currentLogs = from dll in cDataContext.DownloadLogs
             where dll.DTS.Hour == DateTime.Now.Hour
             select dll
```

And then I have another query(also stored as an Iqueryable) that gets the logs that are currently being processed, and dont appear in the logs for that time slot.

```
  notDownloadedIds = (from x in cDataContext.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings
                     where !(
                         from dll in currentLogs
                         select dll.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
                         .Contains(x.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
                     select x);
```

When I debug and hover over currentLogs i see a sql query, when i hover over notDownloadedIDs i see a DataQuery. If i refactor NotDownloadedIDs to not use current logs, notDownloadedIds stays as a sql query, instead of a DataQuery. Why doesnt notDownloadedIds stay as a sql query, and/or how can I get it to stay like that.

If i dont I get problems down the line when use it in a method.

EDIT after using sanders advice i found out the sql statement generated is

```
SELECT ccc.[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID], ccc.[CountryID], ccc.[CategoryID],
ccc.[CategoryTypeID], ccc.[URLSegment], ccc.[DTS], ccc.[DTSUTC]
FROM [Store].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings] AS ccc
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[DownloadLog] AS [t1]
WHERE ([t1].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID] 
<> ccc.[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID])
AND (DATEPART(Hour, [t1].[DTS])) = (DATEPART(Hour, GETDATE()))
)
```

I need to change WHERE EXISTS .... column <> column, to WHERE NOT EXISTS ..... column =column. Is it possible to do this without resolving it to a dataquery?

Comment: But what was the query before? `DataQuery` is still `IQueryable`, so your LINQ query should have produced roughly the same SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are subtle problems where you lose the direct-to-SQL mapping. Without diving into the details (I seem to recall `.Contains()` being problematic), I would recommend you try to refactor your query into a different form, for example:

```
notDownloadedIds = cDataContext.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings.Where(mapping =>
    !currentLogs.Select(dll => dll.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
        .Any(id => id == mapping.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID))
```

If I read your code right, this should result in an equivalent query. Is this also transformed into a DataQuery?

Comment: By god it works, sort of. It keeps it in query form, but my results i think are inaccurate. Ill have to look a little further to see whether  i have to refactor some more, or not.

Comment: I made an edit in my post, if you could help me with it, id appreciate it.

Comment: @Ukemi - I have edited my answer to match your latest addition to the question. Looks like I mistransformed something in the original query. Does this changed one work correctly?

Comment: It did, i would +1 again if i could tyvm

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that since you're incorporating external data (`currentLogs`) as part of your query that Linq-to-SQL is going to pull *all* data from `CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings` and then do the filtering in Linq-to-Objects.

By *why does it matter*?  Certainly there could be a *performance* difference but I owuld expect you to expose the queries as anything other than `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: The problem is that later i have to compare 50k rows to 50k other rows later on, and that is really slow if i dont let sql server do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the amount of objects in your `currentLogs` collection, you can do the following, which should result in a SQL query.

I think the maximum parameter count (which is what your ids will be translated to) for a query is around 2000.

```
var ids = currentLogs
    .Select(x => x.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
    .ToList();
notDownloadedIds = 
    from x in cDataContext.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings
    where !ids.Contains(x.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
    select x;
```

Comment: the 2000 part could very well be the problem. Im working with 50k